# tkinter with Nvidia

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to run a simple tkinter Hello World application

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk("main_screen")
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
ttk.Label(frm, text="Hello World!").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=1, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

But I repeatedly get

```
  File "/home/andrew/.cache/bazel/_bazel_andrew/ffe11784db5d1f88d1cadcbbf8928216/execroot/denarii/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/utils/gui/gui.runfiles/denarii/utils/gui/gui_main.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/andrew/.cache/bazel/_bazel_andrew/ffe11784db5d1f88d1cadcbbf8928216/execroot/denarii/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/utils/gui/gui.runfiles/denarii/utils/gui/gui_main.py", line 57, in main
    root = get_root()
  File "/home/andrew/.cache/bazel/_bazel_andrew/ffe11784db5d1f88d1cadcbbf8928216/execroot/denarii/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/utils/gui/gui.runfiles/denarii/utils/gui/gui_main.py", line 28, in get_root
    return Tk("main_screen")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "main_screen"
```

I have done

```
export DISPLAY_NAME="main_screen"
```

but I still get the error. I cannot run an X-Server because my computer needs to be running the Nvidia drivers. Is there no way to get this to work?

I also tried

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

And it just says that it is not found. So I cannot even start a guiless x server.

Comment: If you don't have an X server running, then what in the world are you expecting Tkinter to *do*?

Comment: Well my question was could it work without one. I guess that answers it!